# How to invalidate particular field in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am having one flow field manager added on screen & in that manager i had added some custom fields.now if i want to change data on particular field only how should i invalidate that particular field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit the custom field to invalidate itself. Say you want to set the text in the customfield. You do

```
field.setText("Test");
```

setText should be

```
public void setText(String text)
{
this.text=text;
invalidate();
}
```

In this way, you can invalidate just the customfield, and only it will be repainted

Comment: Thanks sir,its working great for changing content of one field at a time in manager but if i want to apply it for multiple fields at a same time then it is not working properly.why?what should be the reason behind it?

Comment: how did you try to apply it for multiple fields? please post the code

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void flashScreen(){
    new Thread(){public void run(){
            try{
                int alertLevelColor[]=new int[bedList.size()];

                for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<bedList.size();j++){
                        BedInfo bedInfo=    (BedInfo)bedList.elementAt(j);
                        if(bedInfo.isFlash){
                            BedField bdField=(BedField)vfm.getField(j);
                            alertLevelColor[j]=bedInfo.alertLevelColor;
                            bdField.rePaintField(MvisumAlertMain.appMain.loginUser.backgroundColor);
                        }
                    }
                   Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                    for(int k=0;k<bedList.size();k++){
                         BedInfo bedInfo=(BedInfo)bedList.elementAt(k);
                          if(bedInfo.isFlash){
                            BedField bdField=(BedField)vfm.getField(k);
                            bdField.rePaintField(alertLevelColor[k]);
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                }
            //}
            }catch(Exception e){
                MvisumAlertUtil.saveException("BedListScreen","Flash Screen",e.toString());
            }
        }}.start();  
}
```

Comment: Above is code snippet.in that i want to repaint 3-4 field at a same time so is plz check out the code.